# How to rotate video in video player in adobe flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, actionscript

I am trying to rotate video in default video player in adobe flex by doing:

```
videoPlayer.videoDisplay.rotation = 90;
```

It rotates the video but does not change video width and height. It still displays with small width.

I tried changing video width like:

```
videoPlayer.videoDisplay.width = 600;
```

But with no success.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: So are you saying... the pixels are rotating but the video display size itself remains like un-rotated?  Try `addChild` that `videoPlayer` to some container like sprite or MClip and then only rotate that container instead.

Comment: I removed width and height and it will now set automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the solution for that is to resize your `VideoPlayer` and then you can rotate the `VideoPlayer.videoDisplay` like this :

```
videoPlayer.width = 480;
videoPlayer.height = 270;
videoPlayer.videoDisplay.rotation = 90;
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

At the end i tried following and conclude with as a solved:

```
videoPlayer.scaleMode = "stretch";
```

It will take resize video with full width of the player.